# Most efficient way to fade-in and fade-out circles which are colored using glColorPointer

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am drawing a lot of circles for my android game which uses OpenGL ES 1.1. I use `glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexColors);` to give these circles nice radial gradients.

These circles fade-in and fade-out smoothly, so I some how need to set the alpha value for the whole circle.

Now, I tried `glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, opacity);` but it didn't work. As I discovered in my reserch, `glColorPointer` ignores `glColor4f` calls and unlike textures, `glColor4f` does not modulate the gradient.

Second option is to change the `FloatBuffer vertexColors` which is easy enough

```
for (int i = 3; i < vertexColors.capacity(); i = i + 4) {
    vertexColors.put(i, opacity);
}
```

Now, my circles have 129 vertices each, and there will be 100-150 circles all fading in and fading out, `vertexColors.put` will be called approximately **15,000 times per game loop!** and **375,000 times per second in 25fps** and I have heard `FloatBuffer.put(int index, float f)` is expensive. So, this adds a significant overhead.

So my question is,

Can I in any way set a global alpha value in OpenGL ES 1.1? (I know `glBlendColor` in ES 2.0 can do a lot more but it's not available in 1.1)

or,

Can I some how change the transparency of my circle without changing the vertex colors stored in the `FloatBuffer`?

or,

What would be the most efficient way to fade-in and fade-out circles which are colored using `glColorPointer`?

Comment: Are all the circles different gradients and how/when are these determined (i.e. always the same, at startup, based on input, changing over time)? I'm thinking you will need to resort to using textures and 'tricks' to achieve this, but the accuracy and flexibility would suffer.

Comment: all the vertex color floatbuffers are created while loading the game and ideally should not change in the gameloop... but I am not able to find a way to just change the transparency without changing the vertex colors, I too fear i'll finally have to go with gradient looking textures...

Comment: I would like to be able to do this too; of course with shaders you can send up an alpha multiplier to multiply in, but I haven't found anyway to achieve this in the fixed pipeline. It is a shame, because you can end up with large amounts of VBO colour data which you have to loop through just to multiply in an alpha value.